# how can i display image in a divison in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display the image and text in a div of php but the image is displaying in another line.

```
<div <?php echo apply_filters( 'tester_cover', 'page-cover page-cover--large', array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
    'size' => 'full',
) ); ?>><?php the_candidate_photo(); ?>
    <h1 class="page-title cover-wrapper"><?php the_post(); the_title(); rewind_posts(); ?></h1>

</div>
```

Comment: please describe your question with website link.

Comment: Thanks for help, I am trying to get this result:  please check the link http://prntscr.com/g0x8u4

Answer (score 0):

an `<h1>` tag will by default have CSS of display: block;

give the h1 a class of `inline`, then define a CSS rule:

```
.inline {
    display: inline;
}
```